# What is the difference between pollLast() and removeLast() method of LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

When I see definitions of both methods **pollLast()** and **removeLast()** it looks similar that's It retrieves and removes the last element of a list.

What can be the use case of these methods?

Comment: Minor point of interest: pollLast was added in Java 1.6 when [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) was retrofitted to implement the [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) interface.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these two methods return the last element of the `List`, but `pollLast` returns `null` if the `List` is empty while `removeLast` throws a [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) in this case.

[`pollLast` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pollLast()):

> public E pollLast()
> Retrieves and removes the last element of this list, or returns null if this list is empty.

[`removeLast` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeLast()):

> public E removeLast()
> Removes and returns the last element from this list.
> Throws:
> NoSuchElementException - if this list is empty

Answer (score 1):

[removeLast](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeLast()) will throw an NSEE ([NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html#NoSuchElementException--)) if the list is empty while [pollLast](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#pollLast()) will simply return `null` if it is empty.  Otherwise both will return the item and remove it if the item is present.

Comment: Doesn't removeLast throws NoSuchElementException if list is empty?

Comment: Yes  I had the correct link URL but the wrong text.  Thanks!